# Python: Wrapping functions in the loop

Tags: python, function, wrapper, decorator

What is the correct way to wrap mulptiple functions in the loop in Python?
I have universal wrapper and the list of functions. I need to wrap all functions from the list inside one loop but `for f in funcs:` doesn't work for me. 
What will be the correct way to perform this?

```
def orig_func1(x, y):
    print "x=%i y=%i" % (x,y)

def orig_func2(a, b):
    print "a=%i b=%i" % (a,b)

def wrapper(func):
    f_name = func.__name__
    print 'adding hook for function [%s]' % f_name
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print 'I am before original function'
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print 'I am after original function'
        return ret
    return inner

funcs = [orig_func1, orig_func2]
print funcs

for f in funcs:
    f =  wrapper(f)

print funcs
```

and the results showing that functions from the list are not changed:

```
[<function orig_func1 at 0x022F78F0>, <function orig_func2 at 0x022F7930>]
adding hook for function [orig_func1]
adding hook for function [orig_func2]
[<function orig_func1 at 0x022F78F0>, <function orig_func2 at 0x022F7930>]
x=1 y=2
a=3 b=4
```

Comment: Inside that loop, `f` is nothing but a local variable. You're not changing anything meaningful unless you modify the list directly.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Inside that loop, `f` is nothing but a local variable. You're not changing anything meaningful unless you modify the list directly. Instead of:

```
for f in funcs:
    f =  wrapper(f)
```

You should do this:

```
for i, f in enumerate(funcs):
    funcs[i] = wrapper(f)
```

This will change the functions in your list to new, wrapped ones that you can use. But it still won't change the ultimate definition of the function. Nothing will, once it's been defined, short of a complete redefinition or a wrapper used *right above the function definition*; calling `orig_func1` directly will net the same results before and after the `for` loop. If you want to modify a function at runtime, you'll have to keep referring to this wrapped version of the function that you've just created.

Comment: Alternatively, `funcs = map(wrapper, funcs)`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping over functions trying to wrap them, you should be using [Python Decorators](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/). They are the correct way to modify the behavior of your functions, rather than your current looping method. If the official docs don't make it clear enough, [here](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/) and [here](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/11/29/improve-your-python-decorators-explained/) are a couple of tutorials that helped me quite a bit.

Your existing code actually looks a lot like some of the code snippets from my first tutorial link. You should replace your loop with the `@decorator` syntax instead of the manual wrapping.

That being said, you can accomplish what you originally intended with a comprehension. Replace your loop with this:

```
funcs = [wrapper(func) for func in funcs]
```

The other comments and answers were correct that your modification of **f** in the loop wouldn't work because it had a scope local to that loop and was not modifying your list.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented required behavior using following approach:

```
import Module1, Module2

funcs = ['Module1.func1','Module1.func2','Module2.func1','Module2.func2']
hooks = {}

def wrapper(func,f_name):
    if not hooks.has_key(f_name):
        hooks[f_name] = {'before':[],
                         'after':[]}
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        for f in hooks[f_name]['before']:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        for f in hooks[f_name]['after']:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
        return ret
    return inner

def implementHooks():
    for f in funcs:
        obj_name, func_name = f.rsplit('.',1)
        obj = globals()[obj_name]
        func = getattr(obj, func_name)
        setattr(obj, func_name, wrapper(func, f))

implementHooks()

def module1_func1_hook():
    print 'Before running module1.func1()'

hooks['Module1.func1']['before'] += [module1_func1_hook]
```